# Why Mahabharata battle was fought in Kurukshetra?

Tags: mahabharata, kurukshetra

Why was the Mahabharata battle fought in Kurukshetra and not at any other place? Was there any reason behind that?

Comment: just for information Similar question here,
http://www.quora.com/Epics-and-legendarium-of-India/Any-specific-reason-why-battle-of-Mahabharata-was-fought-in-Kurukshetra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the war of Kurukshetra, Krishna and Arjuna went to find a place suitable for the war.

At one place one farmer was leading water into his fields. That farmer searched for a big stone to stop the flow of water. Meanwhile the farmer’s son came with food for his father. After eating food, the farmer cut his son’s head with a sword and put that head to obstruct the flow of water. The father who was cutting and the son whose head was being cut, were not having any type of emotion during the act of cutting the head. Food is required for feeding the community. The farmer’s aim is to see that the crop grows. The farmer did that job without expecting any return. Sri Krishna choose that place as ‘dharma kshetra’ suitable as ‘war zone’ (yudda kshetra) for the future war between
Kauravas and Pandavas.

Source:-[Sripada SriVallabha Charithamrutham](http://www.good-will.ch/pdf/Sripada_Srivallabha_Charitaamrutam_e.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.